# Android app sms phonenumber filled

Tags: android, sms

For each product from my website there is a link `<a href="sms:phonenumber"> SMS</a>` to send sms, PHONENUMBER is different from one product to another.how can I go through the link and save everything that appears after " sms: " ?
I want to save the phone number in a variable and set this with intend to be filled in sendto adress field,how can i do that?

```
ponumber=???; // this can not be predefine
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
smsIntent.putExtra("address", ponumber);
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","Body of Message");
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

Comment: nobody know a solution for this one?

Comment: Do you mean you want to scrape your own website?

Comment: I want to know how can i pre-populate the TO field with the number from the url!